# MYSQL date query to select enteries in spacific month and year range

Tags: mysql, date

I have got loan entries in my table, `tbl_loan`. It has two attributes, `'start_date'` and `'end_date'`.

Through my `php` form I select a specific year and month. Then I need to select loans according to their start-date and end-date.

For example:

If I select 2015 and May (5th month) then,

- the loan start-date - 2015/2/20, end-date - 2015/10/12 should be
  selected
- the loan start-date - 2015/6/12 should not be selected,
- the loan end-date -2015/4/23 should not be selected.

Thank you!

Comment: You really need to provide more and be more clear with what you're asking. As the question stands, you talk about selecting May 2015, but then that date doesn't appear there after. What do the dates 2015/2/20, 2015/10/12, 2015/6/12 and 2015/4/23 have to do with 2015/5/x? What code have you got/tries and any SQL thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i have taken `$year_selected` as the year and $`month_selected` as the month.

By executing following query in php you will get the deails u needed.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM tbl_loan WHERE $year_selected >= YEAR(start_date) AND $year_selected <=YEAR(end_date) AND     $month_selected >= MONTH(start_date) AND $month_selected <=MONTH(end_date)"
```

Hope this helps